# Tick checkboxes in one cell depending on content in another at the same row level

Tags: javascript, typo3, prototypejs

I need to preselect checkboxes so that I can change their state. Unfortunately I am not a JavaScript guy.

The loop must look something like this

```
tick:
td.col-clipboard input.smallCheckboxes
if:
td.col-clipboard (last-child) contains "sometextstring"
```

Please help, otherwise I would have to tick about 2000 records manually.

Pure JS or Prototype JavaScript framework (version 1.7.1) may be used. It is an older TYPO3 Backend.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Prototype.js makes this pretty straightforward:

```
$$('td.col-clipboard input.smallCheckboxes').select(function(elm){
  return elm.up('tr').down('td:last-of-type').innerHTML.include('sometextstring')
}).invoke(writeAttribute, 'checked', 'checked');
```

You could probably simplify it by selecting the TRs first:

```
$$('tr').map(function(elm){
  if elm.innerHTML.include('sometextstring'){
    elm.down('input.smallCheckboxes').writeAttribute('checked', 'checked');
  }
});
```

If your TRs have a classname or your table has an ID, you can scope the initial selection to just those by changing the outermost `$$` (find all by CSS selector) method's argument to match.

Answer (score 0):

I've created an example that checks each row of the table and set all the checkboxes in that row to `true` if the last cell in that row contains a pre defined variable:

```
const rows = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('tr'));
const str = 'sometextstring';

rows.forEach(row => {
  const cells = Array.from(row.cells);
  // Find last cell in this row
  const target = cells[cells.length - 1].innerHTML;
  // Compare str to the contents of the cell
  if (target === str) {
    // Set all checkboxes in this row to true except the last one
    for (let i = 0; i < cells.length - 1; i++) {
        cells[i].querySelector('input').checked = true;
    }
  }
})
```

My example is case sensitive.

Please find jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/sanderdebr/z23mfthc/34/